# Alamofire: Do af_setImageWithURL and ImageDownloader share the same AutoPurgingImageCache?

Tags: ios, swift, caching, uiimageview, alamofire

I use AlamofireImage in my project a lot like this to set an image to an UIImageView:

```
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: frame)
let URL = NSURL(string: "https://httpbin.org/image/png")!

imageView.af_setImageWithURL(URL)
```

At some point in my app I need to get fetch an image directly, because I want to do something else than setting it to an UIImageView. AlamofireImage provides `ImageDownloader` for this usecase:

```
let downloader = ImageDownloader()
let URLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://httpbin.org/image/jpeg")!)

downloader.downloadImage(URLRequest: URLRequest) { response in
    print(response.request)
    print(response.response)
    debugPrint(response.result)

    if let image = response.result.value {
        print(image)
    }
}
```

Do these two cases **share the same** `AutoPurgingImageCache`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Great question. The answer is `NO`, they do not share the same `AutoPurgingImageCache`.

If you take a look at the `ImageDownloader` initializer, you'll see that it creates a custom `AutoPurgingImageCache` automatically.

```
public init(
    configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration = ImageDownloader.defaultURLSessionConfiguration(),
    downloadPrioritization: DownloadPrioritization = .FIFO,
    maximumActiveDownloads: Int = 4,
    imageCache: ImageRequestCache? = AutoPurgingImageCache())
{
    self.sessionManager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration: configuration)
    self.sessionManager.startRequestsImmediately = false

    self.downloadPrioritization = downloadPrioritization
    self.maximumActiveDownloads = maximumActiveDownloads
    self.imageCache = imageCache
}
```

If you wish to share the same one, then you'll need to download your image on the `UIImageView.af_sharedImageDownloader` instance. A second approach would be to create your second `ImageDownloader` instance using the `AutoPurgingImageCache` property on the `UIImageView.af_sharedImageDownloader`.